# Placing JSON data into a bootstrap list-group

Tags: jquery, json, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to load a set of JSON data into a bootstrap list-group. This has been possible using a table. Although this is not the format I'm looking or (or indeed if its possible to format the table itself with bootstrap classes).

I currently load JSON as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $table = $('#table');
$.getJSON('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheMightyLlama/9f4f1b4c2c078a6080c9212aba6beb59/raw/092fc02afcbd11ea26e7a08541b8dfae4748218a/News%2520Summary%2520Sample', function(mydata) {
});

$(function () {
   $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: mydata
  });  
});
</script>
```

And I can view the results with the below as per this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdpg65v9/):

```
<div class="list-group container">
  <table id="table" data-height="460">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="title"></th>
            <th data-field="date"></th>
            <th data-field="category"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

The end results I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't use Bootstrap table. Just use jQuery to append the list group items.

```
var listgroup = $('#listgroup')
$.getJSON('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheMightyLlama/9f4f1b4c2c078a6080c9212aba6beb59/raw/092fc02afcbd11ea26e7a08541b8dfae4748218a/News%2520Summary%2520Sample',
    function(mydata) {
        for (r in mydata) {
            let title = mydata[r].title
            let date = mydata[r].date
            let cat = mydata[r].category
            let lgi = $('<div class="list-group-item"><span class="badge badge-primary">1</span> ' + title + '</div>')
            listgroup.append(lgi)
        }
})
```

https://codeply.com/p/MwK2uFJWGA